Python code that writes to SQL server not returning correct numbers
I have some Python code that extracts data from an excel spreadsheet and writes to a SQL database.  The SQL database data types are as follows.  Well Name varchar, Date date, Oil Float.  The columns line up well names for example B44 contains the well name.  Where as B78 contains the oil value.  Some oil values are blank or 0.  Here is the code.  And what it is returning.
import os
import pandas as pd

# Define the directory containing the Excel files
directory = r'C:\Users\Justin.Massaro\PycharmProjects\Email\Flash.Tchono@VAALCO.com'

# Initialize an empty DataFrame to store the combined data
combined_data = pd.DataFrame()

# Loop through all files in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx') or filename.endswith('.xls'):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        
        # Load the Excel file
        excel_data = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
        
        try:
            # Extract the required data
            date = excel_data.parse(sheet_name='Feuil1', usecols='B', skiprows=3, nrows=1).iloc[0, 0]
            well_names = excel_data.parse(sheet_name='Feuil1', usecols='B:V', skiprows=43, nrows=1).columns
            oil_data = excel_data.parse(sheet_name='Feuil1', usecols='B:V', skiprows=77, nrows=1)
            
            # Print the extracted oil data to debug
            print(f"Processing file: {filename}")
            print("Extracted oil data:")
            print(oil_data)
            
            # Check if the extracted data is valid
            if len(well_names) == 0 or oil_data.empty:
                print(f"Skipping file {filename} due to missing data.")
                continue
            
            # Transform the columns into rows with the appropriate headers
            data = pd.DataFrame({
                'Date': [date] * len(well_names),
                'Well_Name': well_names,
                'Oil': oil_data.iloc[0, :].values
            })
            
            # Replace 0 or missing values with "Null"
            data['Oil'] = data['Oil'].replace(0, 'Null').fillna('Null')
            
            # Print the data to debug
            print(f"Data from file {filename}:")
            print(data)
            
            # Append the data to the combined DataFrame
            combined_data = pd.concat([combined_data, data], ignore_index=True)
        
        except IndexError as e:
            print(f"Error processing file {filename}: {e}")
            continue

# Print the combined data to debug
print("Combined data before date conversion:")
print(combined_data)

# Convert the 'Date' column to the desired format
if 'Date' in combined_data.columns:
    combined_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(combined_data['Date'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
else:
    print("The 'Date' column is missing in the combined data.")

# Display the combined data
print("Combined data after date conversion:")
print(combined_data)

Here is what it is outputting:
Processing file: DR 24-11-10.xlsx
Extracted oil data:
   Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  519.95491  179.331387  2468.194124  \
0         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN          NaN   

   1600.187764  363.968437  1508.930372  1090.950292  ...  741.731596  \
0          NaN         NaN          NaN          NaN  ...         NaN   

   603.784375  105.052114   0  0.1  0.2  1328.113399  2084.837444  0.3  0.4  
0         NaN         NaN NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN          NaN  NaN  NaN  

[1 rows x 21 columns]
Data from file DR 24-11-10.xlsx:
         Date    Well_Name   Oil
0  2024-11-11       ET-1VA  Null
1  2024-11-11        ET-4H  Null
2  2024-11-11        ET-5H  Null
3  2024-11-11        ET-6H  Null
4  2024-11-11        ET-7H  Null
5  2024-11-11     ET-8H ST  Null
6  2024-11-11        ET-9H  Null
7  2024-11-11       ET-10H  Null
8  2024-11-11       ET-11H  Null
9  2024-11-11       ET-12H  Null
10 2024-11-11     ETSEM-2H  Null
11 2024-11-11     ETSEM-4H  Null
12 2024-11-11     ETBNM-1H  Null
13 2024-11-11     ETBNM-2H  Null
14 2024-11-11    ETBSM-1HB  Null
15 2024-11-11     ETBSM-2H  Null
16 2024-11-11     EAVOM-2H  Null
17 2024-11-11  EAVOM-3HST2  Null
18 2024-11-11     EEBOM-2H  Null
19 2024-11-11     EEBOM-3H  Null
20 2024-11-11     EEBOM-4H  Null
Processing file: DR 24-11-11.xlsx
Extracted oil data:
   Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  519.95491  179.331387  2468.194124  \
0         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN          NaN   

   1600.187764  363.968437  1508.930372  1090.950292  ...  741.731596  \
0          NaN         NaN          NaN          NaN  ...         NaN   

   603.784375  105.052114   0  0.1  0.2  1328.113399  2084.837444  0.3  0.4  
0         NaN         NaN NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN          NaN  NaN  NaN  

[1 rows x 21 columns]
Data from file DR 24-11-11.xlsx:
         Date    Well_Name   Oil
0  2024-11-12       ET-1VA  Null
1  2024-11-12        ET-4H  Null
2  2024-11-12        ET-5H  Null
3  2024-11-12        ET-6H  Null
4  2024-11-12        ET-7H  Null
5  2024-11-12     ET-8H ST  Null
6  2024-11-12        ET-9H  Null
7  2024-11-12       ET-10H  Null
8  2024-11-12       ET-11H  Null
9  2024-11-12       ET-12H  Null
10 2024-11-12     ETSEM-2H  Null
11 2024-11-12     ETSEM-4H  Null
12 2024-11-12     ETBNM-1H  Null
13 2024-11-12     ETBNM-2H  Null
14 2024-11-12    ETBSM-1HB  Null
15 2024-11-12     ETBSM-2H  Null
16 2024-11-12     EAVOM-2H  Null
17 2024-11-12  EAVOM-3HST2  Null
18 2024-11-12     EEBOM-2H  Null
19 2024-11-12     EEBOM-3H  Null
20 2024-11-12     EEBOM-4H  Null
Combined data before date conversion:
          Date    Well_Name   Oil
0   2024-09-05       ET-1VA  Null
1   2024-09-05        ET-4H  Null
2   2024-09-05        ET-5H  Null
3   2024-09-05        ET-6H  Null
4   2024-09-05        ET-7H  Null
..         ...          ...   ...
268 2024-11-12     EAVOM-2H  Null
269 2024-11-12  EAVOM-3HST2  Null
270 2024-11-12     EEBOM-2H  Null
271 2024-11-12     EEBOM-3H  Null
272 2024-11-12     EEBOM-4H  Null

[273 rows x 3 columns]
Combined data after date conversion:
                   Date    Well_Name   Oil
0    September 05, 2024       ET-1VA  Null
1    September 05, 2024        ET-4H  Null
2    September 05, 2024        ET-5H  Null
3    September 05, 2024        ET-6H  Null
4    September 05, 2024        ET-7H  Null
..                  ...          ...   ...
268   November 12, 2024     EAVOM-2H  Null
269   November 12, 2024  EAVOM-3HST2  Null
270   November 12, 2024     EEBOM-2H  Null
271   November 12, 2024     EEBOM-3H  Null
272   November 12, 2024     EEBOM-4H  Null

[273 rows x 3 columns]  The data should look like this Date     Well Name   Oil
11/10/2024  ET-6H   520
11/10/2024  ET-7H   179
11/10/2024  ET-8H ST    2,468
11/10/2024  ET-9H   1,600
11/10/2024  ET-10H  364
11/10/2024  ET-11H  1,509
11/10/2024  ET-12H  1,091
11/10/2024  ETSEM-2H    2,065
11/10/2024  ETSEM-4H    742
11/10/2024  ETBNM-1H    604
11/10/2024  ETBNM-2H    105
11/10/2024  EAVOM-3HST2 1,328
11/10/2024  EEBOM-2H    2,085
11/11/2024  ET-6H   520
11/11/2024  ET-7H   179
11/11/2024  ET-8H ST    2,468
11/11/2024  ET-9H   1,600
11/11/2024  ET-10H  364
11/11/2024  ET-11H  1,509
11/11/2024  ET-12H  1,091
11/11/2024  ETSEM-2H    2,065
11/11/2024  ETSEM-4H    742
11/11/2024  ETBNM-1H    604
11/11/2024  ETBNM-2H    105
11/11/2024  EAVOM-3HST2 1,328
11/11/2024  EEBOM-2H    2,085

All values that do not have an Oil value or are Null should be skipped.  Any help is appreciated.

Remove the rows from data that have 0 or null for oil.  What is the difficulty?  Do you not know how to selectively remove rows from a dataframe?

Where does this code access a SQL server? It's just reading Excel spreadsheets and creating Pandas dadaframes.

Use .dropna() instead of replacing 0 and NA values with the string Null.

I tried that it is closer with the .dropna().  But now getting the NaN on every line.
Extracted well names: Index(['ET-1VA', 'ET-4H', 'ET-5H', 'ET-6H', 'ET-7H', 'ET-8H ST', 'ET-9H',
'ET-10H', 'ET-11H', 'ET-12H', 'ETSEM-2H', 'ETSEM-4H', 'ETBNM-1H',
'ETBNM-2H', 'ETBSM-1HB', 'ETBSM-2H', 'EAVOM-2H', 'EAVOM-3HST2',
'EEBOM-2H', 'EEBOM-3H', 'EEBOM-4H'],
dtype='object')
Extracted oil data:
Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  519.95491  179.331387  2468.194124  
0         NaN         NaN         N
Date    Well_Name  Oil
0  2024-11-11       ET-1VA  NaN
